# Python Requests getting all html data from site

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get product data from [Metal Mulisha](http://www.metalmulisha.com/), I have a list of product IDs that I need to find data on. So I use python with python package requests, with the search URL "http://www.metalmulisha.com/shop/search/?q=20M35518334Z%20M45518403Z%20M45518415Z"

I then use BeautifulSoup to find the class and data I need, but I get an error that says there was nothing there.

So I first went to the URL in Chrome then inspected the elements and all the information I needed was in the html on Chrome.

Here is a snippet of what Chrome showed.

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-2">    
   <div data-rfkid="rfkid_7" data-keyphrase="20M35518334Z M45518403Z M45518415Z" class="rfk_sp rfk-sp">
       <div class="rfk_sp_container" data-nrp="2" data-ntp="2" data-pg="1" data-status="2" rfk_track_appear_once="f=sp,rfkid=rfkid_7,a=1,c=1">
       <div class="rfk_header">
              </div>
        <div class="rfk_message">
        <div class="rfk_msg_noresult">
           </div>
        <div class="rfk_msg_results">Top Results for "20m35518334z m45518403z m45518415z"</div>
```

It keeps continuing under the first div, all I am showing you is there in a lot of information after `<div data-rfkid=`.

Once I ran my python script to find the first div, this is what I get.

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-2">
   <div data-keyphrase="20M35518334Z M45518403Z M45518415Z" data-rfkid="rfkid_7"></div>
    </div>
```

As if all the product information that I need is not there.

Here is my python code, so you can see what I did. I am using python 3.5.

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://www.metalmulisha.com/shop/search/?q=20M35518334Z%20M45518403Z%20M45518415Z"
html = requests.get(url).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

possible_links = bs.find('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-10 col-md-push-2'})
print(possible_links)
```

My question is why can't python find the html I need? If I inspect the site in Chrome I see it just fine, but when I use Python and request the site, it's not there. Is this to do with JavaScript? And if so how do I fix this?

Comment: Not related to the question: You should always use `requests.get(url).content` instead of `.text` if you pass it to a parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: The inside of the div is probably content that is loaded by javascript calls after rendering the initial html, that is why it doesn't show on your requests content. I'm not sure if Requests library can help you with this. You can try dryscrape: https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape

Comment: Here, some reference in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Comment: Lucas, thanks for the input. I could not use dryscrape because it looked like they didn't support windows. So, I looked for other solutions on google, after you said it was related to javascript, and found [this](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/) It uses `PyQt4.QtWebKit` to open the site with its javascript. It's slow, but it worked.

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: I have a list of over 800 product IDs and so I am searching for them in batches of 80(this is because the website cannot handle more then that). I am trying to scrape links to the product pages 'href' so then I can scrape the actual product page. For price, description, image, and color.

Comment: Selenium may be your best bet, http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/